# Passing flash messages in flask framework

Tags: python, flask

I have a use case where, when page2 redirects user to page1, page 1 is supposed to show a flash message (e..g Your order was successfully placed). When a user visits page1 directly without being redirected from page2, I don't show any flash messages.

What is the best way to send flash_message from page2 to page1 while redirect.

Currently I am sending it as a query parameter. Page1 by default has a optional parameter, flash_message, but when user provides flash_message, it shows that flash message.

Is this how flash messages are passed between pages in flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Redirect with parameter**: you set parameter for `page1` link/form on `page2` and if parameter set for `page1` then show message. *Good solution.*
2. **Redirect with special route**: you have special route for `page1` redirection from `page2`. It's similar to parameter.
3. **Redirect with referer**: you check http referer header to `page2` for `page1`. *Good solution, but can have issues with proxies.*
4. **Redirect with anchor**: you set anchor on `page2` and redirect without anchor replacing to `page1`, on `page1` you check anchor and show message. This is best way for me when you have active ajax requests and store session in cookies. *Good solution.*
5. **Store history in storage on frontend**: you save page visiting or message for `page1` on session storage and if `page1` visited after `page2` or message flag set and visited `page1` then show message.
6. **Store history in storage on backend**: you save pages visiting and if `page1` visited after `page2` then show message.

Comment: Great. Thanks! I am using [1] already by passing a (optional)query parameter to page1

Answer (score 0):

It is in the [Documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/flashing/#message-flashing-pattern). You should call the `flash()` method with the message to flash in your view. In the template (for the redirected page) just call the `get_flashed_messages()` to get the message list and print them. If the user came directly there would be no `flash()` call so `get_flash_messages()` will not return any message.

Also every call to `get_flash_message()` will return the same set of messages **for the same request** but will empty out the flash queue for subsequent request. Further information in the [API Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#message-flashing)